# abut curves on a surface

Tags: surfaces, low-dimensional-topology, mapping-class-group

Suppose we have two simple closed curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ on an $n$-times punctured disc $D_n$  which bound the same boundary components. Is it true that there is a $\phi\in MCG(D_n)$(mapping class group of $D_n$) such that $\phi(\alpha)=\beta$? If yes, why is it true? and is the element $\phi$ unique in any sense?

PS: We say a curve $C$ on $D_n$ bounds certain boundary components if they are all inside one of the two regions created by $C$ on $D_n$.

Comment: I edited the problem.

Comment: Use classification theorem in a clever way.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: What happened if you cut the surface along the curves?